# Can I change android app package name manually & without Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, sdk, package

I want to change my android app's package name. I want to do it manually editing all files of the source code. Will this work or anyway I must use Android studio for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do without, but it's a bit of work.

1. Rename the "package" (folders)
2. Edit the package name in the manifest
3. Edit the package name on the first line of every Java file

Now this sounds simple, but depending on how many files there are it can be a very tedious job. Android Studio definitely makes this easier.